# Google Sheets - App Script - Deleting Row(s) based on Matching ID Leaving Header Alone

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Getting close to the final tweaks of the Open Sales Order System Online.

[Google Example Sheet - OSOSO](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/151h1XjB98NOBnO0otNaql3ASjK84CccZZ399dX4BMBM/edit#gid=774458810/)

I am trying to REMOVE/DELETE line items from 'Orders' sheet that are in the 'SHIPPED' sheet.

I have created an ID column so that every line item entered into the 'Order' Sheet will have a unique ID, this Unique ID is carried through the Packing Slip system and on into the 'SHIPPED' sheet.

I would like to REMOVE/DELETE these line items from the 'Orders' sheet once they have been transferred to the 'SHIPPED' sheet.

Because I am a neophyte at coding, I am having some troubles.

Here is the script I have been tweaking to use for the above purpose:

```
function deleteRowInOrders() { 

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var shipped = ss.getSheetByName("SHIPPED");
  var orders = ss.getSheetByName("Orders");

  var shipVal = shipped.getDataRange().getValues();
  var orderVal = orders.getDataRange().getValues();

  var resultArray = [];


    for(var n in orderVal){

  var keep = true
    for(var p in shipVal){ 
      if( orderVal[n][0] == shipVal[p][0]){
        keep=false ; break ;
      }
    }
    if(keep){ resultArray.push(orderVal[n])};
  }
  orders.clear()
  orders.getRange(1,1,resultArray.length,resultArray[0].length).setValues(resultArray);
}
```

The Problem I have;

It strips any formatting on the 'Orders' Sheet.

It deletes the 1st row (header) if they match the 'SHIPPED' sheet.

Thank you for any help and guidance you can offer.

M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I thought to identify duplicate row IDs and save them in an array. Later loop through them and delete one by one. Make sure when you are deleting a row it changes your row counts. To catch that I used `rowsDeleted` variable. Hope this is clear.

```
function deleteRowInOrders()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var shipped = ss.getSheetByName("SHIPPED");
  var orders = ss.getSheetByName("Orders");

  var shipVal = shipped.getDataRange().getValues();
  var orderVal = orders.getDataRange().getValues();
  var rowIDs = [];
  for(var n in orderVal ){
    for(var p in shipVal){ 
      if( orderVal[n][0] == shipVal[p][0]){
        rowIDs.push(n);
      }
    }
  }
  var rowsDeleted = 0 ;

  for(var row in rowIDs)
  {
   var deleteRowID = parseInt(rowIDs[row])+1 - rowsDeleted;
   if(deleteRowID>1) // without header row
   {
     orders.deleteRow(deleteRowID);
     rowsDeleted++;
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Works Great iJay!  I have added it into the shipPS.gs for the Packing Slip, much better.  I also have it added as a separate script in the system for people to look at.